# Porque siempre se antepone EVENT en una condicional, podría haber puesto solo event.keyCode y ahorraría código

Tags: javascript, condiciones, eventos

```
<span onkeypress="if ( event &&  event.keyCode == 32) submitRequest();">Iniciar sesión</span>
<script>
function submitRequest() { //Something to do }
</script>
```

¿Es necesario escribir esta palabra clave EVENT?

Answer (score 1):

La idea de escribir `event && event.keyCode == 32` es asegurarte de que la variable event no sea `null` o `undefined` antes de tratar de acceder a su propiedad `keyCode` para evitar un error. Pero sí puedes evitar repetir el nombre usando el operador `?` ([Encadenamiento opcional](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)) de la siguiente forma:

```
if (event?.keycode == 32){
    submitRequest();
}
```

Comment: Me gusta ese operador, no lo conocia!  La de sintaxis largas que me voy a ahorrar a partir de ahora, gracias por el aporte :-)